# internal hdd disconnecting suddenly by copy in or copy out

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

i have bought an used 3TB internal HDD. the problem is the that while coping something to HDD or error checking with windows or HD Tune pro, it be disconnected in some area of hard disk. i am listening a sound like scratch on disk some times in my case tower. what do you think about this problem? do my HDD has a power problem or so?

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have enough points to comment so I'll leave answer)

I had* the same problem with my drive (WD 2TB Black). After something like two months, I cannot access my drive. 
I tried changing MB, but it didn't fix the problem. Also changing SATA cables or SATA ports on MB didn't help. 
You probably should make sure that your drive is horizontally stable (not tilted). You also could test your drive inside another PC - I did it and now I'm quite sure that it isn't the problem with the drive.
Some sources and answers suggest checking PSU ([HDD disconnects under stress](https://superuser.com/questions/694702/hdd-disconnects-under-stress)). I would advise you to do so. Under the link there are some other suggestions - maybe your problem will be solved by something simpler.

*I still have problems, but now it doesn't make scratch-like sounds.